# upload file when post the form using dropzonejs

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

If i have simple form, and i want to use dropzonejs for uploat multiple files, can i upload them when i post the form?

if i post the form below and print $_FILES i don't get any data...

I looked at other topics here but i got no answer to my question

```
<?PHP
if ($_POST)
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

HTML

```
<form method='post' action='index.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <input type='text' name='title'  value="" class="form-control" />
        <textarea name="msgText" class="form-control" ></textarea>

            <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Attached File:</label>
            <div class="dropzone"></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">           
    </form>
```

Comment: I think you're missing part of your HTML in the question. Where is the beginning `<form>` tag?

Comment: @vqdave - thanks. i edited it